# How to calculate integral of JFreeChart functions

Tags: jfreechart

I have 2 XYSeries (call them f1 and f2) in XYSeriesCollection and I want to calculate integral of (f1 - f2). How can I do that? I don't know formula for f1 and f2, I just have some points to draw plots.

Comment: your question has nothing to do with chart libraries, its pure mathematics. The integral of (f1-f2) is the area covered by f2 without f1. So how to calculate area between dots? Depends on if they are regular or not, and there are several options of interpolation. The simplest one is to take every dot as an edge of the area connected with straight lines. You will be able to find out the rest yourself..

Comment: Points are not regular. So you're telling me that I have to interpolate every value which numerical integration function need?

Comment: no. You can calculate the area between 4 points if you assume they are connected with straight lines. Thats just basic geometry. Sum of this areas is your integral. If you want to work with a fitting function and then numerically solve your integration you just make up information which is not there. Depends a bit on the whole story around this functions (is it an exercise, a measurement, etc?)